# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_receiver'

Tags: python, python-import

when I go to run my program, I keep receiving the error message below:

```
pi@navio:~/cloudapp-raspi $ sudo python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from data_receiver import DataReceiver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_receiver'
```

however, when I go in the app.py file (see below), I clearly have it being imported.

```
import logging, time, argparse, configparser, sys
import socket, os, signal, psutil, data_receiver

from subprocess import Popen
from drone import Drone 
from connection_watchdog import ConnectionWatchdog
from data_receiver import DataReceiver
from utils import Utils
```

Comment: Do you have a `data_receiver.py` in the same directory as `app.py`? Maybe it is spelled differently or in a different location.

Comment: What is `data_receiver`?  A third-party module that you installed?  A custom module you wrote yourself?

Answer (score 1):

`data_receiver` is not a standard python package. If you are installing it from a third party source using a package manager (like `pip`), be sure to install it globally, i.e., something like `sudo -H pip install <package_name>`.

Otherwise, if you have a `data_receiver.py` in your system, make sure to put it in the same directory as your `app.py`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `-H` flag?

Comment: @weBBer `-H` instructs `pip` to use system's home directory for installation. Technically, it's not global installation, but it does the job.